# Access Control in a Web Application

Tags: security, acl, software-design, access-control

I'm currently reading a lot about access control possibilites/mechanisms that can be used to protect resources in an application or web application. There's ACL, RBAC, ABAC and many other concepts out there.

Assuming I have developed a simple webservice that returns knowledgebase articles on a route like '/api/article'. The 'controller' connects to the database and fetches all articles and returns them as XML or JSON.

Now I would like to have control over which article in the database is accessible for which user or group. So for instance if user 'peter' accesses the route '/api/article' with his credentials, the webservice shall return only articles that are visible for 'peter'.

I would want to use ACL to control what each user/group can read/write/delete. But what I don't quite understand:

Where does one enforce the access control? Do I just fetch all records in the controller if a user accesses the route '/api/articles' and check each single record against an access control list (that doesn't sound very good performance wise)? Or is there a way that the 'SELECT' statement to the database only return the records that can actually be seen by that specific user?

I really tried hard to find more information on that topic, and there is a lot about different access control mechanisms, but not about where and how the actual enforcement happens...and it even get's more complex if it comes to other actions like modification, deletion and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really a matter of implementation and everyone does it its own way. It also depends on the nature of the data, particularly on the size of your authorization (do your have 5 roles and users are attached to them or does each user have a specific set of articles he can access, different for each user - for instance)

If you do not want to make the processing on the controller, you could store the authorization information in your database, in a table which links a user to a set of KB articles, or a role (which would then be reflected in the article). In that case your SELECT query would just pass the authenticated user ID. This requires that the maintenance of the relationship is done of the database, which may not be obvious.

Alternatively you can store the ACL on the controller and build a query from there - for specific articles or groups of articles.

Getting all the articles and checking them on the controller is not a good idea (as you mention), DBs have been designed also to avoid such issues.